# R drop columns in a dataframe using a a list of name

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am looking for a way to drop columns in a dataframe based on a list of names.

I have tried several things (like `subset(df,listofcolumn)`), but every time I have a error. My last attempt is trying to loop, but I still have an error:

> "Error in -c(name) : invalid argument to unary operator "

```
discretizedh<-function(h,df){
discret<-discretized(h,df)
coltodrop=NULL
i=1
for(column in discret){
  k=0
  for(data in column){
    k=k+data
}
if(k==0){
    coltodrop=c(coltodrop,colnames(discret[i]))
}
i=i+1
}

for(name in coltodrop){
discret=subset(discret,-c(name))
}
return(discret)
```

Comment: `df[!(names(df)%in% coltodrop)]` would be one way.

Comment: It works perfectly! Many thanks!